# How do I retrieve the binary contents of a longblob column and save as a file?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, file, binary

A *.rar file was saved in a column `longblob`, but it was saved as binary.

How can I build this file in vb.net?

For example I download its binary code with below query.

```
Select file from table where id=1
```

Then do I save it on a variable string? What is the best way for rebuild this .rar?

Comment: How did you get the file in the database in the first place? I imagine the solution would be to do exactly the opposite of that.

Comment: i want to get this file... how do i save? well it is saved since php, but i want rebuild it in vb.net desktop

Comment: do not save it in a string save it in a byte array or stream!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have selected the field, cast the return object into byte[], and do what you need with it.
If you need to send it to a user, through the browser, simple set mime type and filename, and write the byte[] to the outputstream.
This is how I would do it, but with C# code:

```
context.Response.ContentType = ReturnExtension(Extension);
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);

byte[] buffer = (byte[])DB.GetReposFile(id).Rows[0]["FileContent"];
context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Comment: This is for asp.net but there is no mention of doing it in asp.net?